# How to get a URL file name without extension in a webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have this URL (mydomain.com/mypage.aspx). I want to get the file name "mypage" only in a webmethod. I tried the following code but I only get the name of the function itself (MyMethod). I don't get the name of the page from the URL. Any help is well appreciated.

**EDIT** 
To be more specific the webmethod resides in a user control so using FilePath OR PhysicalPath would give me the name of the UserControl file name (MyUserControl) and not the aspx page (mypage) in the URL.

mypage.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<uc:myUserControl runat="server" /> 
</asp:content>
```

myUserControl.cs

```
public static string PageName { get { 
    return (string)(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
        Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url)));
} }
```

OR

```
public static string PageName { get {
    return (string)(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
        HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl));
} }
```

OR

```
public static string PageName { get {
    return (string)(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
        HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath));
} }

[WebMethod]
public static string MyMethod()
{
    StringBuilder SBstring = new StringBuilder();
    SBstring.Append(PageName);
    return SBstring.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use FilePath like this:

```
        var fi = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath);
        var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
```

**Complete working solution for required structure (Master Page -> Content Page -> User Control**

Site Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebTester.Site1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Webform1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTester.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Webform1.aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebTester
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string ProcessIT(string name, string address)
        {
            return WebUserControl1.ProcessIT(name, address);
        }
    }
}
```

WebUserControl1.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebTester.WebUserControl1" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function HandleIT() {
        var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtname.ClientID %>').value;
            var address = document.getElementById('<%=txtaddress.ClientID %>').value;
            PageMethods.ProcessIT(name, address, onSucess, onError);
            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }

            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something is wrong.');
            }
        }
</script>


<div>
    <p>Please enter data:</p>
    Name<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Address<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Signup" OnClientClick="HandleIT(); return false;" />
</div>
```

WebUserControl1.ascx.cs:

```
namespace WebTester
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static string ProcessIT(string name, string address)
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath);
            var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
            string result = string.Format("Name '{0}' and address '{1}' came from Page '{2}'", name, address, fileNameWithoutExtension);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just mocking up something similar. Nice Answer.

Comment: That would give me the name of the cs file where the webmethod resides but not of the aspx main page.... To be more specific the webmethod resides in a user control so using FilePath would give me the name of the UserControl file name.... I want the name of the aspx page.

Comment: Yes that's correct. What Master Page you are looking for? The one that hosts aspx that contains this web method (MyMethod) or the one from Request originated (if you create call from A.aspx to B.aspx)?

Comment: I suggest you post detailed solution (Master Page, aspx and UserControl). This way help can be easier.

Comment: Please poste complete cs and aspx code for your Master, Page and UserControl. This way we would not have to write down code you have already written and it's more likely more people are be willing to help you.

Comment: I have posted complete working solution for you with required arhitecture MasterPage -> ContentPage -> UserControl.